# Show only decimals if the number contains one digit after comma in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view in my MVC Razor website and it shows a partial view with the price of a product.
Now my problem is that i'm showing the price with this partial view:

```
@model decimal
<span>@GlobalModelExtensions.Currency.Symbol</span>
<span>@Model.ToString("N0")</span>
```

This shows a correct price but now my client want that if the price only contains one digit, then he needs to show two decimal places and if the price exceeds one digit then the two decimal places will not be shown.

What's the best approach to achieve that?

```
UPDATE:
This is an example of what i want:
If the price is 90.659 then it must be shown: 91
If the price is 5.659 then it must be shown: 5.66
```

Comment: Could you make an example? I don't really understand what you want..

Comment: Yes.. that's what i want

Comment: Strange requirement.

Comment: Model.ToString(@model<=9.995f ? "#.##" : "#")

Comment: This is because over those prices there is a % discount and if the prices are lowest than 10, then the client want to show the fractional part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put conditional logic in custom number format strings.  The best place put that logic in the model and expose the property as a `string` rather than a floating-point type.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public string FormattedPrice 
    { get 
        {  return Price >= 10 
                ? Price.ToString("#,#")
                : Price.ToString("#,#.00");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer more than mine. This is the right place to do the logic. +1

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
@if(Model > 9){
   <text>@Model.ToString("N0")</text>
}
else
{
   <text>@Model.ToString("N2")</text>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Model.ToString("#.##");`

or

`@Model.ToString("N2");`

> UPDATE: This is an example of what i want: If the price is 90.659 then it must be: 91 If the price is 5.659 then it must be: 5.66

```
if (@Model < 10) @Model.ToString("#.##") else Convert.ToInt32(@Model).ToString()
```

[Console based demonstration here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/znae1f)

Comment: But this will show for all my prices... i only want this for one digit only prices

Comment: @Sippy no it does not, but it's the OPs desire ;D